# Dynamically change STDOUT and STDERR redirections

Tags: perl

In Perl I use standard commands for printing:

```
print "text"; # STDOUT
print STDOUT "text";
print STDERR "text";
```

How can I dynamically change redirection of `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to different files?

Let's say I have a  simple loop with `$i` going from `$min` to `$max` and I want to dynamically change redirections to files `"out_$n"` and `"err_$n"` files where `$n = int($i/1000)`.

I don't want to change my existing `print` commands, so I am looking for solution that would just add this redirection functionality without changing of existing code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just reopen STDOUT

```
open(STDOUT, '>', $qfn)
```

Comment: Will this solution overwrite shell redirection? `app.pl >>out 2>>err` ?

Comment: Yes, there's no difference between a redirected STDOUT and a not redirected STDOUT -- It's all a file handle to the child. By the way, it will even redirect `system "otherscript"`

Comment: When switching from one file to another, do I need to `close` the file handle?

Comment: No explicit `close` needed. In fact, it's best if you don't to make sure it reuses the fd

Comment: So system automatically flush output to previous handle when switched to new one?

Comment: Yes, closing a handle explicitly or otherwise, flushes it first.

Comment: `system` writes to file descriptor 1 (and 2). This might not be `STDOUT`, depending on what order you close `STDOUT` and open other filehandles.